# Copy file(s) containing string to a location oneliner - is there a better way with cmd.exe?

Tags: file, copy, cmd

This

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir *sonic.exe /s /b') do copy /y "%i" D:\temp\utils\
```

The question is there a better or shorter way to do it ?

p.s. I know that "tokens=*" could be omitted if the file path does not have spaces ..

Update: I found a shorter ways of finding ( not copying ) from my old cheat sheets:

```
::START - RUN - cmd.exe
 dir d:\libs\*SubSonic*.dll /s /b>>list.txt&list.txt
:: START - RUN - CMD.EXE 
where /R D:\libs\ *SubSonic*
```

Comment: Is PS completely unacceptable? :P (IMO It's excruciating figuring out this type of stuff in CMD.EXE relative to investing the same time in PowerShell)

Comment: Not at all - but than the question should be  :
Copy file(s) containing string to a location oneliner - is there a better way with PowerShell ?

Comment: But when you have a *really good* hammer... :D

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with [`XCOPY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx).

This will work but will copy the directory structure too which I don't think is what you want:

```
XCOPY /S *sonic.exe D:\temp\utils
```

Comment: Actually it copied only the files containing the string ... 

  XCOPY /S *sonic.exe D:\temp\utils\tmp
D:ORM\SubSonic_2.1_Final_Source\src\SubCommander\bin\Debug\sonic.exe
D:ORM\SubSonic_2.1_Final_Source\src\SubCommander\obj\Debug\sonic.exe
2 File(s) copied

Comment: It will only copy matching files, but if the source file is in a subdirectory called bin then a destination file will be put in a subdirectory called bin too.  The FOR loop wouldn't do this, but if you want the subdirectories in the destination then XCOPY is definitely what you want.

Comment: Yep , the folder structure was unneeded and did not exactly answered the question ... I was way to fast to mark the answer without properly testing it ... Anyway thanks for the answers and comments !!!

Comment: You can unmark my answer as accepted.  Just click on it again.  I'd like to find out the best answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
dir -r -i *sonic.exe | select-string "tokens=" | % {cp $_ d:\temp\utils}
```

? [in PS]

Comment: +1 for providing working sample. Thanks. Simple theory without working code about problems discussed here is not very useful ...

Comment: Amusingly, I normally dont post code and send theory (and dont get +1s :D)! (And I didnt test this, though I do similar stuff regularly). If you're interested in PS, there is a new edition of the Payette book on the way to add to your wishlist - it's probably best for devs (there are lots of other good books on PS out there too)